# Output form of a result

Tags: output-formatting, code-request

Suppose I computed something with *Mathematica*, and the result is in the form

> ```
> Gamma[1 + N]^2
> ```

How can I tell *Mathematica* to write the result in a more comprehensive way? I mean something to write to get information about what `Gamma[1 + N]^2` is (I know what is that, it's an example!) in terms of Tex view or in terms of an expansion of its meaning?

Comment: `Informaton@Gamma`

Comment: thaaaanksssss!!

Comment: By the way, N is a reserved word in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

```
?? Gamma
```

or

```
Information[Gamma]
```

will yield all the information available through *Mathematica*.